# Spectral decomposition of the resolvent map

Tags: functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics

Let $P_\Omega$ be a projection valued measure and let $R_A(z)=(A-z)^{-1}$ be the resolvent map.
It can be shown that $$R_A(z)=-\sum_{j=0}{\frac{A^j}{z^{j+1}}}$$

whenever this series is defined.

My question is, given a self adjoint operator $A$, and the fact that we know that $A$ = $\int \lambda P(d\lambda)$, 
how to proof that 
  $$ R_A(z) = \int\frac{1}{\lambda-z}dP(d\lambda)$$

This is assumed in [Frederic Schuller lecture 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPHpioiCDoM&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxQVx5jRjbfRGEzWY_upS5K6&index=11)

Answer (score 1):

This follows from a general property of integrals with respect to projection-valued measures associated to self-adjoint operators. Namely, if $P$ is the unique projection-valued measure such that 
$$A=\int\lambda \,P(d\lambda) $$ 
then for all $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ Borel measurable and bounded on $\sigma(A)$, in symbols $f\in B(\sigma(A))$, we have
$$f(A)=\int f(\lambda)\,P(d\lambda) \qquad (\star)$$
Where $f(A)$ is defined in the sense of the (Borel) functional calculus (see e.g. [these notes](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-fa/fa.pdf), pag. 178). Even if you do not know the functional calculus, it suffices for you to know that if $z\notin \sigma(A)$ (otherwise $R_A(z)$ is not defined) and $f(\lambda)=f_z(\lambda)=(\lambda-z)^{-1}$, then we have $f_z(A)=(A-z)^{-1}$, as one would obtain by formally replacing $\lambda$ with $A$ in the expression of $f_z$.

Indeed, let us check that $f_z\in B(\sigma(A))$. Since $z\notin \sigma(A)$, $f_z$ is continuous on $\sigma(A)$ and since $\sigma(A)$ is compact, $f_z$ is also bounded. Therefore, substituting in $(\star)$ we obtain 
$$(A-z)^{-1}=\int \frac{1}{\lambda-z}\,P(d\lambda) $$
as desired.